# Pipe communication between 4 children processes only works the first time

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

I wrote this program that taken N number of arguments, and sends them from first child process to the last. Second child adds 20% to the value he received and the third child adds 30%. 

The problem is that the first child always sends only the first argument. I can not seem to find the bug. Can someone help me solve this problem? Here is the example of the output:

```
./prodajnaVerigaAnon 200 100 50
312 312 312
```

It should be: 312 156 78.
Here is the code:

```
for(int i=1;i<argc;i++) {
     char init_price[size];
     const int len = sprintf(init_price,"%d",atoi(argv[i]));
     write(fd1[1], init_price, (size_t) len + 1);
}
close(fd1[1]);
_exit(0);
```

EDIT: I deleted most of the code, because it was a school assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is,

```
write(fd1[1], init_price, (size_t) len + 1);
```

write function send 200 through pipe fd1[1] but no reader was available, that's why pipe did not get chance to flush out, still 200 is exist in pipe.
so your pipe is not able to get more input.

when

```
  read(fd1[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
```

available, it finds only 200 in pipe so read only that value.

if you want to see change then put sleep, you will observe reader able to read other data too. because sleep help to context switch.so reader process will available to listen on pipe.

```
for(i=1;i<argc;i++) 
{
     char init_price[size];
     const int len = sprintf(init_price,"%d",atoi(argv[i]));
     write(fd1[1], init_price, (size_t) len + 1);
     sleep(2);
 }
 close(fd1[1]);
 _exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipes are a stream of data.  The number of reads does not necessarily equal the number of writes.

What happens in this case is that the first child does three writes to the pipe, then the second child reads all three values in a single read.  You aren't checking the return value of `read` to see how many bytes have been read.

After calling `read`, check the return value to see how many bytes were read.  Then use `strtol` instead of `atoi` to convert the value.  The former allows you to pass in a pointer will on return will point to the spot in the buffer where the conversion stopped.  You can then continue reading from there until the buffer is exhausted, then call `read` again.